# Loopy integral $\int xe^x\sin(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration

How to find integral of: $$\int xe^x\sin(x)$$
I know it should be repeated integration by parts, but i do not know how many times i should do this and when to stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have by integration by parts $$\int x\sin\left(x\right)e^{x}dx=-\frac{1}{2}x\cos\left(x\right)e^{x}+\frac{1}{2}x\sin\left(x\right)e^{x}-\frac{1}{2}\int e^{x}\sin\left(x\right)dx+\frac{1}{2}\int e^{x}\cos\left(x\right)dx
 $$then we have again by integration by parts $$-\frac{1}{2}\int e^{x}\sin\left(x\right)dx=\frac{1}{2}e^{x}\cos\left(x\right)-\frac{1}{2}\int e^{x}\cos\left(x\right)dx
 $$then$$\int x\sin\left(x\right)e^{x}dx=-\frac{1}{2}x\cos\left(x\right)e^{x}+\frac{1}{2}x\sin\left(x\right)e^{x}+\frac{1}{2}e^{x}\cos\left(x\right)+C
 $$so you need two times integration by parts.

Answer (score 6):

You had better use the formula $\sin x = \dfrac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2}$. In this way you obtain an integral like $\int xe^{ax}dx$ and it is easy to reach your goal by integration by parts.

Also, another ways are possible.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the traditional way.

Hint: If the notation is $\int udv = uv -\int vdu$, then go back and look at the original integral. The part $\sin(x)$ can be either differentiated twice and get "same thing", or integrated twice. Therefore you should let it be either $u$ or $dv$. Then look at $xe^x$. Is it easy to differentiate or integrate? Of course the former! So $xe^x$ should be $u$ and $\sin(x)$ should be $dv$. Then use the formula.

Another trick you may want to know: If you get $\int fdx = g + C\int fdx$, where $C \not= 1$, then you are actually done, since $\int fdx = \frac{g}{1-C}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int xe^x\sin x dx =\text{Im}\left(\int xe^x e^{ix}dz\right)=\text{Im}\left(\int xe^{(1+i)x}dx\right)$$

Then, use integration by parts,.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of $\sin x$ as the imaginary part of $e^{ix}$. Then the integral is the imaginary part of

$$\int x\,e^xe^{ix}\,dx = \int x\,e^{(1+i)x}\,dx $$

Using integration by parts

$$ \begin{align}
\int x\,e^{(1+i)x}\,dx &= x\frac{e^{(1+i)x}}{1+i} - \int \frac{e^{(1+i)x}}{1+i} dx \\
&= x\frac{e^{(1+i)x}}{1+i} - \frac{e^{(1+i)x}}{(1+i)^2} + C \\
&= \frac{1 - i}{2}x\,e^{(1+i)x} - \frac{(1-i)^2}{4}e^{(1+i)x} + C \\
&= \frac{1 - i}{2}x\,e^{(1+i)x} + \frac{i}{2}e^{(1+i)x} + C
\end{align}  $$

Taking the imagrinary part 
$$\Im \left\{\frac{1 - i}{2}x\,e^{(1+i)x} + \frac{i}{2}e^{(1+i)x} + C\right\}
= \frac{1}{2}x\,e^x\sin x - \frac{1}{2}x\,e^x\cos x + \frac{1}{2}e^x\cos x + C $$

Answer (score 0):

$$ \int x e^x \sin{x} \, dx = xe^x \sin{x} - \int e^x \sin{x} \, dx - \int xe^x \cos{x} \, dx $$
because $(x\sin{x})'=\sin{x}+x\cos{x}$. The first integral can be done by integrating by parts twice. The last integral:
$$ -\int xe^x \cos{x} \, dx = -xe^x \cos{x} + \int e^x \cos{x} \, dx - \int xe^x\sin{x} \, dx, $$
which contains the original integral; you can then solve for it. $\int e^x \cos{x}$ works in the same way as $\int e^x \sin{x} \, dx$.

Answer (score -1):

Treat x*sinx as first term and e^x as the 2nd term. Then use integration by parts.